# Retry DbDataAdapter.Fill after reconnection

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a code to fill a DataTable from db using a SqlCommand with select sql and DbDataAdapter. During filling rows to DataTable there is sometimes a loss of DbConnection, which is handled and second attempt of adapter.Fill() is called:

```
int FillSafe(DataTable dataTable)
{
    try
    {
        return adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (connectionErrorManager.HandleDisconnectionAndSecurityErrors(ex))
        {
            // Re-try fill function if error was properly handled
            return adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

adapter is local field initialized with command:

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter((SqlCommand)selectCommand);
```

And connectionErrorManager.HandleDisconnectionAndSecurityErrors() basically closes and reopens SqlConnection object (same instance).

It seems to be working fine, but there is a problem for tables without primary key - some data rows are become duplicated in DataTable.
I.e. following test fails with 5 rows instead of 3:

```
public void TestFillDoesnotProduceDuplicateRowsAfterDisconnect()
{
    const string Query = @"
SELECT 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C'";

    var table = new DataTable();
    table.RowChanged += (o, e) =>
    {
        if (table.Rows.Count == 2)
        {
            Db.Connection.CloseConnection();
        }
    };

    using (var command = Db.Connection.Command(Query))
    using (var adapter = command.NewDataAdapter())
    {
        FillSafe(table);
    }

    AssertEquals(3, table.Rows.Count);
}
```

If I try to clear DataTable before refilling it

```
table.Rows.Clear();
```

test fails with exception about closed DataReader:

```
Exception Type: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.
StackTrace:
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
at className.FillSafe[T](DataTable dataTable)
at className.TestFillDoesnotProduceDuplicateRowsAfterDisconnect()
```

So I have 2 questions:

1. Why table.Rows.Clear() causes such difference in behaviour? How does it closes DataReader?
2. How to solve it? I need to clear already loaded rows and refill table again.

Comment: Seems that table.Rows.Clear() does not closes a reader on the adapter/command, but somewhere on the table itself, because using new DataTable for refilling after reconnection (and after clearing rows in original table) completes without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the issue, and it was in my test code.
I have manually closed connection when specific count of rows was loaded, and after cleaning table and refilling, connection was closed again, triggering new unhandled exception.